# Linq to Entity - error on ICollection<Guid> (code first)

Tags: c#, linq, entity-framework, exception, linq-to-entities

so We used a code first approach to build the database. I have come across an issue and am having very little success resolving it. the DB class (EF - code first)

```
public partial class Object1
{
    [Key]
    public Guid uid { get; set; }
    public int sequenceNumber { get; set; }
    public bool triggerFlag { get; set; }
    public ICollection<Guid> Object2 { get; set; }
    public ICollection<int> Object3 { get; set; }
}
```

Throws an error when trying to retrieve objects of specific conditions related to the internal collections

the code that errors  I have tried a few different linq methods to try and resolve the error but none have worked (dc is dataCOntext in EF)

```
        return JsonConvert.SerializeObject(dc.Object1.Where
            (x => (!x.Object2.Any() || x.Plants.Contains(object2UID))
             && (x.Object3.Count == 0 || x.Object3.Contains(Object3)).ToList());
```

The error produced is

> An unhandled exception of type 'System.NotSupportedException' occurred
>   in EntityFramework.SqlServer.dll
>
> Additional information: The specified type member 'Object2' is not
>   supported in LINQ to Entities. Only initializers, entity members, and
>   entity navigation properties are supported.

```
public partial class Object2
{
    [Key]
    public Guid uid { get; set; }
    [Required]
    [StringLength(50)]
    public string model { get; set; }
    [StringLength(3)]
    public string Type { get; set; }
    [StringLength(10)]
    public string alias { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: Thats probably because Object2 is not in your Object1 table schema. If Object2 is linked to another table by foreign key then you need to configure it and `Include` it to pull its value. Also, in that event you need to declare that property as `virtual`.

Comment: @rageit yea, the database only shows the 3 columns that are not collections. however this format is used elsewhere and works. the funny thing is, it throws the same error on object3 if I just remove object2 from the linq

Comment: Please add Object2 class? Why would you want a navigation property collection of Guid's?

Comment: Forgot to add Object2 is probably not part of the table schema and therefore cannot be mapped

Comment: @dellywheel I will update above, and the concept of using the Guids, is that we do not want any direct links between tables like foreign keys (not my choice) but it works out for the concept of this project.

Comment: surely better to have an `ICollection<Object2> Object2s` and then create a joining table using `FluentApi' I cant see how EF would ever work with your code above. I can post what I mean but not sure its what you're after

Comment: @dellywheel If i just changed from guid to object references EF would create the junction tables for me, I was just hoping to remove any dependancy between the tables. but either way It looks like a small db change is in order.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The "no foreign keys" rule eliminates one of the big advantages of relational databases, but you don't have to have foreign keys to join objects together in EF.  However, you do need the foreign keys if you expect to use the navigation property feature of EF.

You should be able to do something like:

```
public partial class Object1
{
    [Key]
    public Guid uid { get; set; }
    public int sequenceNumber { get; set; }
    public bool triggerFlag { get; set; }
    public Guid Object2Id { get; set; }
    public int Object3Id { get; set; }
}

public partial class Object2
{
    [Key]
    public Guid uid { get; set; }
    [Required]
    [StringLength(50)]
    public string model { get; set; }
    [StringLength(3)]
    public string Type { get; set; }
    [StringLength(10)]
    public string alias { get; set; }
}

public partial class Object3
{
    [Key]
    public int uid { get; set; }
    // Other fields...
}
```

And retrieve them like:

```
var objects = from o1 in dc.Object1
              join o2 in dc.Object2 on o1.Object2Id equals o2.uid
              join o3 in dc.Object3 on o1.Object3Id equals o3.uid
              select new
              {
                  Object1 = o1,
                  Object2 = o2,
                  Object3 = o3
              };
```

Having said all that, since there is a relationship between Object1, Object2, and Object3, then I would suggest using relational databases and Entity Framework the way they were designed to be used...  Add foreign keys.